# React Native-Weather App-Testing on iPhone error (using expo snack editor)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, openweathermap

I am trying to create a Weather App. It works fine on web but does not work on my phone. I am using the expo online snack editor to test this.
screenshot of the error:
[image: error]

All of my code is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@rpshende/weather-app-copy)

screenshot of snack editor "web" tab result:
[image: result]

I also tested it in the "iOS" tab of the snack editor & it has the same error as on my phone.

P.S. to get the exact result shown in the screenshot inside of snack:

1. Go to the Open Weather API website
2. Sign up for an account
3. Get your API key from the email that was sent to you
4. Go into **functions/fetchWeather.js** in snack editor
5. On line 2, replace where it says "redacted" with your api key that you got from that email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because your code has a string outside from a `Text` component. Line 45 has a `{' '}` and it needs to be wrapped for the `Text` component from `react-native`. Your code will be something this:

```js
// Rest of the code above

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <RequestLocation />
      <Text>Weather App</Text>
      <Text>Weather for your location today:</Text>
      <Weather
        morn={Math.round(this.state.temp['morn'])}
        day={Math.round(this.state.temp['day'])}
        eve={Math.round(this.state.temp['eve'])}
        night={Math.round(this.state.temp['night'])}
        max={Math.round(this.state.temp['max'])}
        min={Math.round(this.state.temp['min'])}
      />
      <Text>{' '}</Text>
      {/* Showing weather with passed values from this file to the main weather component
      (code de-cluttering) */}
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can read more about it in [this section of the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#limited-style-inheritance).

Comment: oof I forgot to delete that. that was just from some testing

Comment: I dunno how those curly brackets got there but thank you! it worked